# MalformedPolicyDocument: Policy document should not specify a principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-policies, terraform-aws-modules

I am trying to create a state function with terraform. First I create a policy and assign it to an existing role `processing_lambda_role`.

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "sfn_policy" {
  policy = jsonencode(
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "states.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:InvokeAsync"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
  ]
}
  )
  role = aws_iam_role.processing_lambda_role.id
}


resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "sfn_state_machine" {
  name     = local.step_function_name
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.processing_lambda_role.arn

  definition = <<EOF
{
  "Comment": "Get Incoming Files",
  "StartAt": "GetIncomingFiles",
  "States": {
    "GetIncomingFiles": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "${aws_lambda_function.get_incoming_lambda.arn}",
      "ResultPath": "$.Output",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
EOF
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Error putting IAM role policy terraform-20211117095209110000000005: MalformedPolicyDocument: Policy document should not specify a principal.
│       status code: 400, request id: 1dd8ac18-a514-4ef3-93ae-91383e5baa07
│ 
│   with module.ingest_system["ems"].aws_iam_role_policy.sfn_policy,
│   on ../../modules/ingest_system/step_function.tf line 1, in resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "sfn_policy":
│    1: resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "sfn_policy" {
```

and that's how the role was originally defined:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "processing_lambda_role" {
  name = local.processing_lambda_role_name
  path = "/service-role/"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version   = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = { Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com" }
        Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Comment: The sts:AssumeRole stuff needs to be part of the trust relationship of processing_lambda_role, not part of the policy. Or what do you want the AssumeRole within the policy to achieve?

Comment: Would be more convenient for me to change the roles/policies than the trust relationship. Is that possible? @luk2302

Comment: Depends on what you want to be doing, if you want to allow statemachine or lambda to assume the role, then no, you need to put that stuff into the trust relationship. If you want to allow the role to assume other roles then you can put that stuff into the policy. That is how IAM works.

Comment: You mean the same exact error you reported after my answer persists? Or you have new issue?

Comment: it's an issue with Sts:AssumeRole within the state function policies so a different error but probably because of the AssumeRole @Marcin Now, I think I am only "assuming" twice, which might not be what I am supposed to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sts:AssumeRole` should be in role's `assume_role_policy`. For example, if you want to create `sfn_role` for your sfn, then:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "sfn_role" {
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version   = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = { Service = "states.amazonaws.com" }
        Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "sfn_policy" {
  policy = jsonencode(
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [    
    {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:InvokeAsync"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
  ]
}
  )
  role = aws_iam_role.sfn_role.id
}

resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "sfn_state_machine" {
  name     = local.step_function_name
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.sfn_role.arn
  # ....
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure how is it different from my code? I am already giving ```Sts:AssumeRole``` in the ```processing_lambda_role```, no? What part am I missing?

Comment: @x89 Your `aws_iam_role_policy.sfn_policy` has `Principal`, which is incorrect. It should be as in my example.

Comment: If I remove the Principal/service part, I still get an error ```Policy statement must contain resources.```

Comment: @x89 So add `"Resource": "*"` or more specific if you wish.